# Compiling a .sys driver using command line tools (cl.exe | link.exe)

Tags: c, windows, compilation, kernel, driver

I am getting deeper into how internals of compilation process work, in other words - what is going on behind the scene when I press the build button in MSVS.

- I have build the solution and the project with "KMDF Driver, Empty" preset in MSVS
- I have the source code of a simplest driver (x86_64) possible, just the entry and the unload routine:

```c
#define _AMD64_ // required only when I compile via command line tools, MSVS does not like it, and I comment it out when I compile with MSVS.
#include <wdm.h>

void DriverUnload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObj) {

    DbgPrint("Unloaded...");
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObj, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegPath) {

    DriverObj->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

    DbgPrint("Loaded!");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

So, about the problem itself.

Compiling within MSVS:

- After pressing the build button (running MSBuild.exe behind the scene) compilation goes on well without any errors.
- Then, after loading the driver.sys and creating an associated service via *sc create ...* it is being considered as **STOPPABLE**, and I am able to stop it.
- **This is the intended behavior**.

Compiling with command line tools:

- cl driver.c "D:\Windows kits\D:\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\km\x64\NtosKrnl.lib" /I"D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\km" /link /SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE /DRIVER /KERNEL /ENTRY:DriverEntry
- When I compile the same source code via command line tools with command above - compilation executed properly, and then I rename the outputted driver.exe into driver.sys - it loads up properly as well.
- However, in this case, after creating an associated service, the driver is considered as **NOT_STOPPABLE** and I am unable to stop it.

Why so? What can affect the "stoppability" of a driver? The source code is exactly the same (except #define AMD64), so the problem must lie somewhere in the compilation process.

I've tried to copy all the options of cl.exe compiler from MSVS directly (Project Configuration -> C/C++ -> Command Line Options) and same for linker, but this did not work, as there is a ton of options and all them require different sort of libraries, environment variables defined, etc...

That's why I am here - looking for help from experienced low-level programmers:) Maybe somebody can point me in the right direction, so I can at least narrow down the scope of the problem.

Comment: Figure out how your IDE builds the file?  "did not work" is not useful debug info.  You should tag this with your OS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379576/making-windows-legacy-driver-non-stoppable-programmatically?

Comment: @AllanWind I have already searched through all related questions, I am not helpless, but anyways, thank you. About the "did not work" - what I meant was it is not the right approach, I did not work because simply copying the command line options from MSVS project preferences and running cl.exe with them is unlikely to work as in these options lots of environment variables are mentioned, specifying them all manually as the cl.exe options is pure hell.

Comment: Unable to reproduce using VS2019 and WDK 10.0.19041. Both binaries perform identically for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "KMDF Driver, Empty" creates a matching .inf file, and the default installation would be unloadable, for development and debugging.

How are you "loading" your version? Do you have a .inf file? What does it contain?

Comment: Asking for additional information should go into a comment, not into an answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this important thing, David. The .inf file is created by MSVS at the project startup, and as far as I understand it is used only when I compile the driver within MSVS. Because when I compile it via command line, I do not specify any options related to that .inf file, and it is located not in the project directory where the source code is located. I load my driver in "Disable Driver Signature enforcment" Windows mode, simply by creating a service like so: "sc create mydrv bin_path= ...\driver.sys type= kernel" and then start it with sc start mydrv

Comment: Also, I load both drivers (compiled with MSVS and with command line) in the VM, simply by dragging just the .sys file and creating the service there. So the VM knows nothing about the .inf file, however the behavior is different, as mentioned.